React component doesn't get updated prop
Can't figure out why i see in console updated inferringStatusType, but at 'switch' construction component NewWinOrderGantt didn't updated inferringStatusType prop.
 const { inferringStatusType, additionalUserInference } = useSelector(
    state => state.mainLayout
)

useEffect(() => {
    switch (curModalOptionType) {
        case 'diagram_orders':
            setTabs(tabs => [
                ...tabs,
                {
                    name: 'Диаграмма Ганта - Заказы',
                    component: () => <NewWinOrdersGantt showInferringLoader={inferringStatusType} />, //here component did't get updated inferringStatusType
                    id: uuid(),
                },
            ])
            openDiagrammTypeModal.onClose()
            setCurOptionModalType(null)
            break

        default:
            break
    }

}, [curModalOptionType, inferringStatusType])


Hi, I am not able to get the question completely. Do you expect that all records in the variable array tabs would get the latest value of the prop inferringStatusType ? All records in the sense, let us say, the first record added to the array when inferringStatusType is 'A', and then the second record added when inferringStatusType is 'B'. Now which value you would expect to see for the first record, 'A' or 'B' ?

I think it's must be "B". I mean NewWinOrdersGantt shoud always recieve updated prop showInferringLoader, that's why i added inferringStatusType to dependecy.
